# How to use Outlook URLs like "outlook:<long hex number>" from another program?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Inside Outlook (for the Windows desktop), I can use URLs like `outlook:<long hex number>` to link to specific items like emails. How can I use the same URL from another program to open the given item (assuming that Outlook is running and has the right .pst file loaded)?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out how to do this, and thought it might be worthwhile to post it anyway.

I followed the instructions in [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to create an entry for the URL scheme `outlook`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:Outlook Protocol"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE,1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\outlook\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE\" /select \"%1\""
```

Now I can link to Outlook items (like emails) from e.g. Obsidian.

I use URLs like `Outlook:000000005C21B4389B9D9445A4687127BE2120CCC4CC4200` that I obtain with an old utility called "Linker for Windows".

The original download location is not available anymore, and I don't want to link to third-party download sites for which I don't know whether they are trustworthy, so here is the "About" dialog:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, glad to see it is resolved. This will benefit others in the forum who have similar issues.